# Add-in forces OWA reload in Edge only

Tags: outlook-addin, microsoft-edge, office-js, outlook-web-app

We are working on an Outlook office.js add-in. It works in Outlook for Windows and Mac, and OWA for Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE (with some separate issues with Safari and IE) but OWA Edge is crashing OWA just by loading a task pane triggered by an add-in command. By crash what I mean is it successfully loads the task pane, and then the UI freezes for about 5-10 seconds, then OWA reloads itself.

When this happens an error appears in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe, version: 11.0.15063.483, time stamp: 0x595f2577
Faulting module name: RPCRT4.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xcf94c546
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000001539b
Faulting process id: 0x176c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d315f28d6ef0f7
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
Report Id: b6162eec-9330-4481-a33c-b6d4411d9a43
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_40.15063.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: ContentProcess
```

Some details:

1. Some users have no crashes
2. Others crash on every task pane
3. One user only crashed on task panes when an asynchronous operation was triggered.

We are at a loss on how to proceed in looking into this issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Update: It turned out to be some code we wrote that Edge does not like. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Carbo. Sounds like either office.js or your add-in is triggering some sort of a browser issue. Do you mind sharing the manifest so we could try this ourselves? Are affected users Office 365 users?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in console when this happens?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I do not see any errors in the console.

Comment: So the reset may not be a crash so much as a timeout. Blocked execution for 5-10s will cause it to be flagged unresponsive. Could you add a description/code showing what your doing at launch of the add-in? Something is getting stuck in a loop or otherwise blocking execution.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT If this is a timeout, why would it affect Edge only? Is Edge more stringent? This occurs even for the simplest task pane - an About task pane that shows the version and a link. The only thing that might be doing once it loads is checking the application cache.

Comment: If you share your add-in manifest, we can give it a try and see if we can reproduce and dig a bit into it..

Comment: We discovered that if we clear the browser cache, the task pane loads and OWA does not crash. During this initial load our application cache pulls down all of our files. When we load the next task pane the cache is just checked and no files are pulled down, but after about 5 seconds OWA reloads. If we completely disable the application cache then everything works. Does that give anyone any ideas?

Comment: At this point we need a reliable repro to debug with. Is there a Manifest you can provide? Or it does sound like the application cache is the cause, is there a small debug app you can provide us that repros the problem?

Comment: It turned out to be something we did. We had code to look for our app cache manifest to help detect offline status. Edge did not like that code. Sorry to bother everyone. Thanks for your efforts.